# Boxplot label outliers according to third variable

Tags: r, label, boxplot

I am trying to create a boxplot where the outliers are labelled according to a third variable and not row names.

My data looks as follows: (now edited to contain multiple countries and sector as a factor variable)

```
country <- c(rep(LETTERS[1:5],2))
sector <- rep(c("one", "two"),5)
set.seed(200)
value <- round(rnorm(10),2)
dat <- data.frame(country,sector,value)
dat

   country sector value
1        A    one  0.08
2        B    two  0.23
3        C    one  0.43
4        D    two  0.56
5        E    one  0.06
6        A    two -0.11
7        B    one -1.02
8        C    two -0.30
9        D    one  0.17
```

10        E    two  1.42

Without the labels the boxplot is like this:

```
boxplot(value ~ sector, data=dat)
```

I want the labels on the outlier points to reflect the values for the variable country.

I found a similar question here: [Labeling outliers on boxplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181086/labeling-outliers-on-boxplot-in-r) and I am trying to adapt the code as follows:

```
bxpdat <- boxplot(value ~ sector, data=dat)
text(bxpdat$group+0.2,                                           
bxpdat$out,                                                 
dat$country[which( dat$value == bxpdat$out, arr.ind=TRUE)[, 1]])
```

However I seem to be doing something wrong because this is not working. I would greatly appreciate a suggestion how to fix this code,

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response! it does work on the sample data I have provided here, however on my real data it did not work...perhaps this is because the original data has many more countries. For example when I try to define the variable country as `country <- c(rep(LETTERS[1:5],2))` with the code you provided it writes for both cases the same label...

Comment: have you tried @MichaelChirico solution ? this should work on your real data too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight adjustment:

```
x <- boxplot(value ~ sector, data=dat)

text(x$group, x$out,
     labels=subset(dat, sector %in% x$group & 
                     value %in% x$out)$country, pos=4)
```

This is not a great general solution since the `subset` matching might accidentally hit other points. This will work better but I'm not sure how to do it in `base`:

```
library(data.table); setDT(dat, key = c("sector", "value"))

dat[ , {
  x <- boxplot(value ~ sector, data=dat)
  with(x, text(group, out, .SD[.(group, out), country], pos = 4))}]
```

Comment: @Cath with different values of country, you mean?

Comment: In that case, adjust to  `.SD[.(group, out), paste(country, collapse = ", "), by = .(sector, value)]`, but as you mentioned, this is unlikely

Comment: thanks a lot, the base suggestion works on the sample data even if I re-define with more countries. I will now try on the original data set. Do I understand correctly there might be a problem if there are the same values but they are not outliers for example in other sectors? Does the data.table solution avoid that?

Comment: @ZMacarozzi I believe so, but only if those other sectors _also_ have outliers (at different values). The `data.table` solution was specifically tailored to handle this.

Comment: can I just ask one more detail: I am not able to apply the base solution to my own data set because in my data the sector is a factor and not an integer; so in the example data set if I define sector as `sector <- rep(c("one","two"),5)` and I run your code, I get the error as follows: `Error in text.default(x$group, x$out, labels = subset(dat, sector %in%  : 
  zero-length 'labels' specified` . is there a way to adapt the base solution to work with a factor? I am now going to try the data.table solution as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Zmacarozzi `as.integer(sector) %in% ...`

Comment: Thanks! I applied it and I don't get an error but there are outliers in all sectors (in total 6) so the text gets overlapped. The data.table solution works with the sector as in integer but if I adapt for a factor it does not work `library(data.table); setDT(dat, key = c("sector", "value"))
dat[ , {
  x <- boxplot(value ~ as.integer(sector), data=dat)
  with(x, text(group, out, .SD[.(group, out), country], pos = 4))}]`

Comment: once more thanks for your help! I managed to get the data.table solution to work, however, I first have to convert the variable sector to integer `dat$sector <- as.integer(dat$sector)`; if I just use `as.integer(sector)` inside the code it does not work. But really thanks for your help, my report is coming very nice now!